# Selecting a specific item with value in a sass map

Tags: css, sass

I have a sass `map` which looks like this:

```
$settings: ("offset": 'margin-left',
    "push": 'left',
    "pull": 'right',
    "center": 'margin-left');
```

Underneath that i have a function that loops from `1` to a specific variable wich with the value of `12`.

```
  @for $index from 1 to 12 {
    @each $type, $property in $settings {
      &.#{$type}-#{$index} {
        @include someFunctionDoesntMatter($property, $index);
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, i'm already selecting data from that sass `map`but not specific ones, i'm just looping all of it.

How can i select the `4`th item in the map inclusive the value?

I have tried this piece of code under the last bracket of the loop:

```
  &.#{nth($settings, 4)} {
     ...
  }
```

But that gave me this error:

```
cmd.exe /D /C C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update main.scss:main.css
      error features\grid\_grid-extensions.scss (Line 19: Invalid CSS after "&.": expected class name, was ""center" "margi...")

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: if the list index is zero based than 3 is the last index

Comment: @philipp Can you be more specific please? I dont get it.

Comment: normally list indices are zero based, so if you have a list `l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, then `l[0] => 'a'` and `l[3] => 'd'`, whereby `l[4]` is not in the list, since it refers to the fifths entry. In your case, I guess `&.#{nth($settings, 3)}` should yield `"center": 'margin-left'`

Comment: UHHH… excuse me… I am wrong… http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists/ sass lists indices start at `1`, so they not zero based… The mistake must be somewhere else…

Comment: @Dreiba what output you would like to achieve? .center .margin-left { ... } for example ?

Comment: There i'm calling up that `function` wich is also included in the code above it. But then it has different arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nth($settings, 4)` will return the key value pair not a value you can use to build your selector.

You could do it like this instead:

```
$settings: ("offset": 'margin-left',
    "push": 'left',
    "pull": 'right',
    "center": 'margin-left');

div {   
  &.#{nth(nth($settings, 4), 1)} {
    content: nth(nth($settings, 4), 2);
  }
}
```

Which would render:

```
div.center {
  content: "margin-left";
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/b8e6c2dc02b0d3df52b7

Comment: thanks, but do you recommend using maps for this? Or should i better use another way?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about the context. I use maps in `@each`-loops like the one you mentioned in your question. If I needed to also use one key-value pair for something else I might do it like this, but it does tend to make the Sass harder to read and to predict the output when you write it like this.